# Onion skin isn't showing but I checked everything I was supposed to. How do I fix this?

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d, draw-mode

[image]

I tried to add a keyframe to my animatic, but the onionskin won't show, I swear I have everything checked. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I guess I was on render mode, and that made the onion skin not visible. I should've been on the preview display.

Comment: I think you have to enable the option *View in Render* for it to be visible while in rendered viewport, but it will also be visible in full rendering. See [Blender Manual — Onion Skinning](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/onion_skinning.html)